# Apache Maven: cannot find symbol and invalid target release error (NetBeans support for Mule Plugin)

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run following command on following project:

```
mvn clean package nbm:cluster nbm:run-ide
```

Project URL: https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/mule-netbeans (Netbeans Support for Mule)

I tried it on Apanche Maven 3.0.4 and 3.0.5 but unable to run it.

I tried it with Java 6, Java 7 and Java 8.

With Java 7 and Java 8 i am getting following issues:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Mule Netbeans XML
[INFO] Mule Support Plugin
[INFO] Mule Tools for NetBeans
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mule Netbeans XML 0.5
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\src\main\java\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\xml\UserCatalogProcessor.java:[38,37] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping Mule Tools for NetBeans
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Mule Netbeans XML ................................. FAILURE [1.471s]
[INFO] Mule Support Plugin ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mule Tools for NetBeans ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.154s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 04 08:53:45 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project mule-netbeans-xml: Compilation failure
[ERROR] D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\src\main\java\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\xml\UserCatalogProcessor.java:[38,37] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

With Java 6, i am getting following:

```
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: invalid target release: 1.7
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

POm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.mule.tooling.netbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-netbeans</artifactId>
    <name>Mule Tools for NetBeans</name>
    <description>NetBeans Support for Mule</description>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans-version>RELEASE82</netbeans-version>
    </properties>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License 2.0</name>
            <url>http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- NetBeans 6.9+ requires JDK 6, starting NetBeans 7.4 source 1.7 is required -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.15</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <!--<module>mule-netbeans-runtime</module>-->
        <!--<module>mule-netbeans-api</module>-->
        <!--<module>mule-netbeans-config</module>-->
        <module>mule-netbeans-xml</module>
        <module>mule-netbeans-plugin</module>
    </modules>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>netbeans</id>
            <name>Repository hosting NetBeans modules</name>
            <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/nexus/content/groups/netbeans</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Could anyone assist where i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're running Java 6 when the build source is Java 7.  Why do you still have Java 6 installed at all?  It hasn't been supported in years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done following Changes to execute it perfectly.

> Java 8, Apache Maven 3.0.5

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
```

Output:

```
Scanning for projects...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Build Order:

Mule Netbeans XML
Mule Support Plugin
Mule Tools for NetBeans

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Mule Netbeans XML 0.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
Deleting D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
Compiling 2 source files to D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\target\classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
No sources to compile

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
Tests are skipped.

--- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
Building jar: D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\target\mule-netbeans-xml-0.5.jar

--- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ mule-netbeans-xml ---
Installing D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\target\mule-netbeans-xml-0.5.jar to C:\Users\harpreetsi\.m2\repository\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\mule-netbeans-xml\0.5\mule-netbeans-xml-0.5.jar
Installing D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-xml\pom.xml to C:\Users\harpreetsi\.m2\repository\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\mule-netbeans-xml\0.5\mule-netbeans-xml-0.5.pom

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Mule Support Plugin 0.8-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Deleting D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 39 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Compiling 63 source files to D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\classes

--- nbm-maven-plugin:4.0.1:manifest (default-manifest) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
NBM Plugin generates manifest
Adding on module's Class-Path:
    org.mule.tooling.netbeans:mule-netbeans-xml:jar:0.5
    org.jdesktop:beansbinding:jar:1.2.1

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 12 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Compiling 2 source files to D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\test-classes

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Tests are skipped.

--- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Adding existing MANIFEST to archive. Found under: D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
Building jar: D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar

--- nbm-maven-plugin:4.0.1:branding (default-branding) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
No branding to process.

--- nbm-maven-plugin:4.0.1:nbm (default-nbm) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Copying module JAR to D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\nbm\netbeans\mule\modules with manifest updates
Generating Auto Update information for org.mule.tooling.netbeans
No updater.jar specified, cannot validate Info.xml against DTD
Building jar: D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\nbm\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.nbm

--- maven-install-plugin:2.5:install (default-install) @ mule-netbeans-plugin ---
Installing D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\harpreetsi\.m2\repository\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\mule-netbeans-plugin\0.8-SNAPSHOT\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
Installing D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\pom.xml to C:\Users\harpreetsi\.m2\repository\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\mule-netbeans-plugin\0.8-SNAPSHOT\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
Installing D:\mule-netbeans-master\mule-netbeans-plugin\target\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.nbm to C:\Users\harpreetsi\.m2\repository\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\mule-netbeans-plugin\0.8-SNAPSHOT\mule-netbeans-plugin-0.8-SNAPSHOT.nbm

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Mule Tools for NetBeans 1.1
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mule-netbeans ---

--- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ mule-netbeans ---
Installing D:\mule-netbeans-master\pom.xml to C:\Users\harpreetsi\.m2\repository\org\mule\tooling\netbeans\mule-netbeans\1.1\mule-netbeans-1.1.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reactor Summary:

Mule Netbeans XML ................................. SUCCESS [5.716s]
Mule Support Plugin ............................... SUCCESS [23.561s]
Mule Tools for NetBeans ........................... SUCCESS [0.069s]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 33.336s
Finished at: Thu May 04 09:30:43 IST 2017
Final Memory: 30M/394M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's even better, did you really downloaded the code and compiled it? awsome...

Comment: Yes. Downloaded to local and build at local and was stuck actually. But careful hit and trials worked. Moving to Next step is packaging as mentioned by Author in plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

try to change to maven2 and you have to add this additional info in the pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerVersion>1.5</compilerVersion>
    <source>1.5</source>
    <target>1.5</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME to your jdk7 home directory, for example on Microsoft Windows:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40"
or on OS X:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home